# Appending values to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary to which I want to append to each drug, a list of numbers. Like this:

```
append(0), append(1234), append(123), etc.

def make_drug_dictionary(data):
    drug_dictionary={'MORPHINE':[],
                     'OXYCODONE':[],
                     'OXYMORPHONE':[],
                     'METHADONE':[],
                     'BUPRENORPHINE':[],
                     'HYDROMORPHONE':[],
                     'CODEINE':[],
                     'HYDROCODONE':[]}
    prev = None
    for row in data:
        if prev is None or prev==row[11]:
            drug_dictionary.append[row[11][]
    return drug_dictionary
```

I later want to be able to access the entirr set of entries in, for example, `'MORPHINE'`.

1. How do I append a number into the drug_dictionary?
2. How do I later traverse through each entry?

Comment: You may wish to setup your drug_dictionary as a `drug_dictionary = defaultdict(list)`. That way you don't have to define your drugs with empty lists beforehand, but you can just do `drug_dictionary[ drugname ].append( list )` without having the key predefined. `defaultdict` requires `from collections import defaultdict` I think.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just use append:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [123, 234, 456]
d = {'a': [], 'b': []}
d['a'].append(list1)
d['a'].append(list2)
print d['a']
```

Comment: Just to add, this is the output of the above: ```[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [123, 234, 456]]``` and this is the how the complete list looks like afterwards. ```{'a': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [123, 234, 456]], 'b': []} ```

Answer (score 21):

You should use append to add to the list. But also here are few code tips:

I would use `dict.setdefault` or `defaultdict` to avoid having to specify the empty list in the dictionary definition.

If you use `prev` to to filter out duplicated values you can simplfy the code using `groupby` from `itertools`
Your code with the amendments looks as follows:

```
import itertools
def make_drug_dictionary(data):
    drug_dictionary = {}
    for key, row in itertools.groupby(data, lambda x: x[11]):
        drug_dictionary.setdefault(key,[]).append(row[?])
    return drug_dictionary
```

If you don't know how groupby works just check this example:

```
>>> list(key for key, val in itertools.groupby('aaabbccddeefaa'))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a']
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `update()` method as well

```
d = {"a": 2}
d.update({"b": 4})
print(d) # {"a": 2, "b": 4}
```

Comment: IMHO the correct form is "d.update({"b": 4})".

Answer (score 5):

It sounds as if you are trying to setup a list of lists as each value in the dictionary. Your initial value for each drug in the dict is `[]`. So assuming that you have list1 that you want to append to the list for `'MORPHINE'` you should do:

```
drug_dictionary['MORPHINE'].append(list1)
```

You can then access the various lists in the way that you want as `drug_dictionary['MORPHINE'][0]` etc.

To traverse the lists stored against key you would do:

```
for listx in drug_dictionary['MORPHINE'] :
  do stuff on listx
```

Answer (score 4):

To append entries to the table:

```
for row in data:
    name = ???     # figure out the name of the drug
    number = ???   # figure out the number you want to append
    drug_dictionary[name].append(number)
```

To loop through the data:

```
for name, numbers in drug_dictionary.items():
    print name, numbers
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to append to the lists of each key inside a dictionary, you can append new values to them using `+` operator (tested in Python 3.7):

```py
mydict = {'a':[], 'b':[]}
print(mydict)
mydict['a'] += [1,3]
mydict['b'] += [4,6]
print(mydict)
mydict['a'] += [2,8]
print(mydict)
```

and the output:

```
{'a': [], 'b': []}
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [4, 6]}
{'a': [1, 3, 2, 8], 'b': [4, 6]}
```

`mydict['a'].extend([1,3])` will do the job same as `+` without creating a new list (efficient way).

Answer (score 2):

how do i append a number into the drug_dictionary?

Do you wish to add "a number" or a set of values?

I use dictionaries to build associative arrays and lookup tables quite a bit.

Since python is so good at handling strings, 
I often use a string and add the values into a dict as a comma separated string

```
drug_dictionary = {} 

drug_dictionary={'MORPHINE':'',
         'OXYCODONE':'',
         'OXYMORPHONE':'',
         'METHADONE':'',
         'BUPRENORPHINE':'',
         'HYDROMORPHONE':'',
         'CODEINE':'',
         'HYDROCODONE':''}


drug_to_update = 'MORPHINE'

try: 
   oldvalue = drug_dictionary[drug_to_update] 
except: 
   oldvalue = ''

# to increment a value

   try: 
      newval = int(oldval) 
      newval += 1
   except: 
      newval = 1 


   drug_dictionary[drug_to_update] = "%s" % newval

# to append a value  

   try: 
      newval = int(oldval) 
      newval += 1
   except: 
      newval = 1 


   drug_dictionary[drug_to_update] = "%s,%s" % (oldval,newval)
```

The Append method allows for storing a list of values but leaves you will a trailing comma

which you can remove with

```
drug_dictionary[drug_to_update][:-1]
```

the result of the appending the values as a string means that you can append lists of values as you need too and

```
print "'%s':'%s'" % ( drug_to_update, drug_dictionary[drug_to_update])
```

can return

```
'MORPHINE':'10,5,7,42,12,'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vowels = ("a","e","i","o","u") #create a list of vowels  
my_str = ("this is my dog and a cat") # sample string to get the vowel count
count = {}.fromkeys(vowels,0) #create dict initializing the count to each vowel to 0                                                                    
for char in my_str :  
    if char in count:  
       count[char] += 1  

print(count)
```

Comment: I hope you understand it better