# python (simple) append to dictionary error

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to loop through a list of split words to make a dictionary, using the first word as a key, and the proceeding word as a value (as in google's basic python exercises: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/basic).

I am getting the error message: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'" with the code below:

```
def mimic_dict(filename):
"""Returns mimic dict mapping each word to list of words which follow it."""
mimic = {}
f = open(filename, 'r')
fulltext = f.read()
splittext = fulltext.split(' ')

for c in range(len(splittext)-1):
    if splittext[c] in mimic:

#Error on the next line
        mimic[splittext[c]].append(splittext[c+1])
    else:
        mimic[splittext[c]] = splittext[c+1]
```

I have been trying to use the method here: [Appending values to dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419147/appending-values-to-dictionary-in-python)
but without success.  I'm sure my error is simple, but i have spent seemingly ages on this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `mimic[splittext[c]]` is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`splittext[c]` is a string and you are trying to append to it (which, of course, fails).

Did you mean to say `mimic[splittext[c]] = [splittext[c+1]]` in your last line? Note the angular brackets, you need to add a `list` to the `mimic` dictionary in order to append more elements to it later.

Comment: BTW, it's more pythonic to do `for i, element in enumerate(splittext)` to automatically get  both the element and its index at the same time. Just be careful at the very last element/index, because `splittext[i+1]` will throw an `IndexError`.

Comment: You should look at [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful and clearly something I overlooked in the tutorial, I appreciate the help.

Comment: BTW 2: you can further simplify your loop by using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict): `mimic = defaultdict(list)` and you don't need to check whether a particular key already exists, defaultdict will initialize a new empty list for you on first access.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `.append()` on `splittext[c]`, which is a the string contained at index `c` of the list `splittext`. You cannot use `.append()` on a string.