# Collect dict frames in a python object with appropriate and fast data structure

Tags: python, oop, dictionary, data-structures

I'm using an API which provides 128 signals (and signal quality values) per second as a dict in a dict. I want to collect them into windows of 1 (or more)  seconds.

My native approach was to use the same dict structure and append the values to lists (Like this: [Appending values to dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419147/appending-values-to-dictionary-in-python)).

See the example:

```
# the API provides data like this
def getFrame(i):
    return {"X":
                {"value" : i,
                 "quality": i*2},
             "AF3":
                {"value" : i*3,
                 "quality": i*4}
             }


# object to collect single frames
class WindowDto(object):
    def __init__(self, windowSize, header):
        self.header = header
        self.windowSize = windowSize
        self.data = {}
        for key in self.header:
            self.data[key] = {"value": [], "quality": []}

    def addFrame(self, frame):
        for key, val in frame.iteritems():
            field = self.data[key]
            field["value"].append(val["value"])
            field["quality"].append(val["quality"])


# the keys of a frame are known
header = ["X", "AF3"]
# the max frame count is also known, but not used yet
maxFrameCount = 8        

dto = WindowDto(maxFrameCount, header)
for i in range(8):
    dto.addFrame(getFrame(i))

print(dto.data)
# {'X': {'quality': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14], 'value': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, 
#  'AF3': {'quality': [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28], 'value': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]}}
```

I assume the `addFrame()` method is a potential bottleneck, as I have to iterate over the whole structure. I am looking for a smarter way to perform the `add` operation. Any suggestions how to do this?

I am also free to change the way the values are stored (e.g. in an array?) to improve performance. I know the header values and the max size of a window object. The values are later processed as lists (e.g. `sum(data["X"]["values"])`), but the access is wrapped by the `WindowDto`.

Comment: Why do you think this is a performance problem, and what sort of access pattern would be better than iterating over the items in the returned object?

Comment: As an aside, this doesn't seem very OOPish at all.  If the array entries are related (i.e. quality[n] is the pair of value[n] and they don't make sense without each other) they should probably be encapsulated into a single object for each pair (basically a tuple, possibly with some decorations).

Comment: if you are expected to report the frames (`print(dto.data)`) towards the end, you can accumulate the frames as is and do the aggregation during the reporting.

Comment: @tripleee I am also unsure, if there is a better way, that's why I asked, as I thought I missed something obvious. Encapsulation `value` and `quality` (I think a tuple is good) would be an approach. This would probably make it cleaner and saves 1 dict hierarchy.

Comment: @srj good point, the expense would be the same or do you see any better way to do it at the end?

Comment: If the collecting is critical but the printing is not, refactoring the expenses to the printing loop makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do any profiling,maybe what you have is already good enough for your server?!

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('for i in range(128):dto.addFrame(getFrame(i))')
         899 function calls in 0.001 seconds
cProfile.run('for i in range(128**2):dto.addFrame(getFrame(i))')
         114691 function calls in 0.046 seconds
```

Comment: No I didn't do profiling - maybe I should have - it was just a feeling that the structure I have at the moment is not the best solution. Thanks for the code.

Comment: You've been right, the current structure had the best performance, so there is no need to change the data structure.