# Appending values in a list in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I am trying to add values to a list inside a dictionary. I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419147/appending-values-to-dictionary-in-python) and tried `append`, but I get an error.

Code:

```
def name_counts(x):
    firsts = {}
    for full in x:
        part = full.split()
        fn = part[0]
        if fn in firsts:
            firsts[fn].append(full)
        else:
            firsts[fn] = []
            firsts[fn] = full
    return(firsts)


name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
print(name_counts(name_list))
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Desired output:

```
{'Shelba': ['Shelba Barthel', 'Shelba Crowley', 'Shelba Fernald', 'Shelba Odle', 'Shelba Fry'],'David': ['David Joyner', 'David Zuber'], 'Brenton': ['Brenton Joyner', 'Brenton Zuber'], 'Maren': ['Maren Fry'], 'Nicol': ['Nicol Barthel']}
```

Comment: `firsts[fn] = full` ...?

Comment: Try `firsts[fn] =full` as `firsts` is a dictionary.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev what do you mean "try"? That line is the *problem*.

Comment: seems like a good use case for `defaultdict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the list you are immediately replacing it with a string.
Try:

```
if fn in firsts:
    firsts[fn].append(full)
else:
    firsts[fn] = [full]
```

instead of

```
if fn in firsts:
    firsts[fn].append(full)
else:
    firsts[fn] = []
    firsts[fn] = full
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def name_counts(x):
firsts = {}
for full in x:
    part = full.split()
    fn = part[0]
    if fn not in firsts:
        firsts[fn] = []

    firsts[fn].append(full)
return(firsts)


name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
         "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
         "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
         "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
print(name_counts(name_list))
```